# Can anyone explain me why my order of output is like this

Tags: javascript, async-await

This is the js code

```js
async function inc(x){
  x= x + await 1 ; 
  return x;
}

async function increment(x){
  x+=1 ;
  return x ; 
}
const sub = async(x) =>{
  return x-2 ; 
}

inc(1).then((x) =>{
  increment(x).then((x) =>{
    console.log(x);
  })
})

sub(3).then((value)=>{
  console.log(value) ; 
})

console.log("we are here\n");
```

The order is we are here, 1, 3. I understand why the values are coming so but I can't understand their order.

Comment: async code is added at the bottom of execution stack, so it will be executed after the `console.log`. because they are not really async code, the order is prefixed by the fact that the first block has 2 `then`, so it is added once at the bottom, then the second block is added, finally the inner `then` of the first block.

Comment: When I am removing the second  `then` still the answer is "we are here" 1 , 2, order is same

Answer (score 0):

Using `.then` without a proper `async/await` code is quite equivalent to the following, I added comments so that you can see the execution priorities in the call stack:

```js
function inc(x){
  x= x + 1 ; 
  return x;
}

function increment(x){
  x+=1 ;
  return x ; 
}
const sub = (x) =>{
  return x-2 ; 
}


const x = inc(1);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('the first block executed')
  const y =increment(x);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('the inner block of the first block executed')
     console.log(y);
  });
});


const z = sub(3)
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('the second block executed')
   console.log(z);
});

console.log("we are here\n");
```

Comment: Can you explain the behavior when we don't have the inner `then`, then also the order remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function without an `await` expression will run synchronously though `async` function returns a Promise.

A promise executed as a microtasks, so it will first wait for all other tasks except macro task to be completed.

Hence it first print `we are here` then the next `synchronous` operation. So it print `1`.

But an awaits waits until the Promise is fulfilled, so it print `3` at last

Comment: Can you explain the behavior when we don't have the inner then, then also the order remains the same

Comment: Already explained, does not matter if you are using inner then

Comment: OK, but still a promise is not executed. Only functions execute. Not promises. It is the code we provide to be executed when a promise resolves that is executed. This is the `then`-callback, or the resumed function (in case of `await`).